# Add margin left after second div and margin should get increase double

Tags: jquery

Need to Add margin left after second div and margin should get doubled.

FOR EXAMPLE:
3rd li margin left - 220
4rd li margin left - 440
and so on.

```
<ul>

    <li id="new-3">3</li>
    <li id="new-4">4</li>

</ul>

$(function (){  
    var jn=220;
    $('ul').find('li').each(function (){
            jn += parseInt($(this).css('margin-right')) + 220;
        alert(jn);
        })   
        $('li').css("margin-right",jn)  
    })
```

Here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/t688b/8/

Comment: Did you mean doubled or get incremmented by `220`..?

Comment: both are same for me double of 220 i need exactly.but that i can change in function.you can add any value and make it double

Answer (score 3):

```
$('ul li:gt(1)').css('marginLeft', function(i, m){
   return parseInt(m, 10) + (++i * 220);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pzHHH/

Comment: @SACHIN Yes, if you don't want to use current margin of the elements, `m` is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

See : http://jsfiddle.net/b8uXm/

```
$(function (){  
var jn=0;
$('ul').find('li').each(function (){

    alert(jn);
    $(this).css("margin-left",jn);
    jn += parseInt($(this).css('margin-left')) + 220;
    })   

})
```

Comment: hey i want it start from 2nd li

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var jn = 220;
        $('ul').find('li').each(function () {
            jn += parseInt($(this).css('margin-left')) + 220;
            alert(jn);
            $(this).css("margin-left", "" + jn + "px");
        })

    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function (){  
    var jn=220;
    $('ul').find('li').each(function (){
            jn += parseInt($(this).css('margin-left')) + 220;
        //alert(jn);
        $(this).css("margin-left",jn) 
        })

    })
```

You can double the margin or increase it according to your requierment.